# onDataPointClick function doesn't work - react-native-chart-kit

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I'm using this library: [react-native-chart-kit](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/)

I want to catch user's click on `line-chart`.

this is my code:

```
      <LineChart
        onDataPointClick={()=>console.log('masoud')}
        data={{
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
          datasets: [{
            data: [
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100
            ]
          }]
        }}
        width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // from react-native
        height={Dimensions.get('window').height}
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
          backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
          backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
          decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
          color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16
          }
        }}
        style={{
        }}
```

but `onDataPointClick={()=>console.log('masoud')}` doesn't called at all.

this is whole source code of `line-chart` of this library:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'
import {Svg, Circle, Polygon, Polyline, Path, Rect, G} from 'react-native-svg'
import AbstractChart from './abstract-chart'

class LineChart extends AbstractChart {
  getColor = (dataset, opacity) => {
    return (dataset.color || this.props.chartConfig.color)(opacity)
  }

  getStrokeWidth = dataset => {
    return dataset.strokeWidth || this.props.chartConfig.strokeWidth || 3
  }

  getDatas = data =>
    data.reduce((acc, item) => (item.data ? [...acc, ...item.data] : acc), [])

  renderDots = config => {
    const {
      data,
      width,
      height,
      paddingTop,
      paddingRight,
      onDataPointClick
    } = config
    const output = []
    const datas = this.getDatas(data)
    data.map((dataset, index) => {
      dataset.data.map((x, i) => {
        const cx =
          paddingRight + (i * (width - paddingRight)) / dataset.data.length
        const cy =
          (height / 4) *
            3 *
            (1 - (x - Math.min(...datas)) / this.calcScaler(datas)) +
          paddingTop
        const onPress = () => {
          if (!onDataPointClick) {
            return
          }

          onDataPointClick({
            value: x,
            dataset,
            getColor: opacity => this.getColor(dataset, opacity)
          })
        }

        output.push(
          <View key={Math.random()}>
            <Circle
              cx={cx}
              cy={cy}
              r="4"
              fill={this.getColor(dataset, 0.9)}
              onPress={onPress}
            />
            <Circle
              cx={cx}
              cy={cy}
              r="12"
              fill={this.getColor(dataset, 0)}
              onPress={onPress}
            />
          </View>
        )
      })
    })
    return output
  }

  renderShadow = config => {
    if (this.props.bezier) {
      return this.renderBezierShadow(config)
    }

    const {data, width, height, paddingRight, paddingTop} = config
    const output = []
    const datas = this.getDatas(data)
    config.data.map((dataset, index) => {
      output.push(
        <Polygon
          key={index}
          points={
            dataset.data
              .map(
                (x, i) =>
                  paddingRight +
                  (i * (width - paddingRight)) / dataset.data.length +
                  ',' +
                  ((height / 4) *
                    3 *
                    (1 - (x - Math.min(...datas)) / this.calcScaler(datas)) +
                    paddingTop)
              )
              .join(' ') +
            ` ${paddingRight +
              ((width - paddingRight) / dataset.data.length) *
                (dataset.data.length - 1)},${(height / 4) * 3 +
              paddingTop} ${paddingRight},${(height / 4) * 3 + paddingTop}`
          }
          fill="url(#fillShadowGradient)"
          strokeWidth={0}
        />
      )
    })
    return output
  }

  renderLine = config => {
    if (this.props.bezier) {
      return this.renderBezierLine(config)
    }

    const {width, height, paddingRight, paddingTop, data} = config
    const output = []
    const datas = this.getDatas(data)
    data.map((dataset, index) => {
      const points = dataset.data.map(
        (x, i) =>
          paddingRight +
          (i * (width - paddingRight)) / dataset.data.length +
          ',' +
          ((height / 4) *
            3 *
            (1 - (x - Math.min(...datas)) / this.calcScaler(datas)) +
            paddingTop)
      )

      output.push(
        <Polyline
          key={index}
          points={points.join(' ')}
          fill="none"
          stroke={this.getColor(dataset, 0.2)}
          strokeWidth={this.getStrokeWidth(dataset)}
        />
      )
    })

    return output
  }

  getBezierLinePoints = (dataset, config) => {
    const {width, height, paddingRight, paddingTop, data} = config
    if (dataset.data.length === 0) {
      return 'M0,0'
    }

    const datas = this.getDatas(data)
    const x = i =>
      Math.floor(
        paddingRight + (i * (width - paddingRight)) / dataset.data.length
      )
    const y = i =>
      Math.floor(
        (height / 4) *
          3 *
          (1 -
            (dataset.data[i] - Math.min(...datas)) / this.calcScaler(datas)) +
          paddingTop
      )

    return [`M${x(0)},${y(0)}`]
      .concat(
        dataset.data.slice(0, -1).map((_, i) => {
          const x_mid = (x(i) + x(i + 1)) / 2
          const y_mid = (y(i) + y(i + 1)) / 2
          const cp_x1 = (x_mid + x(i)) / 2
          const cp_x2 = (x_mid + x(i + 1)) / 2
          return (
            `Q ${cp_x1}, ${y(i)}, ${x_mid}, ${y_mid}` +
            ` Q ${cp_x2}, ${y(i + 1)}, ${x(i + 1)}, ${y(i + 1)}`
          )
        })
      )
      .join(' ')
  }

  renderBezierLine = config => {
    const output = []
    config.data.map((dataset, index) => {
      const result = this.getBezierLinePoints(dataset, config)
      output.push(
        <Path
          key={index}
          d={result}
          fill="none"
          stroke={this.getColor(dataset, 0.2)}
          strokeWidth={this.getStrokeWidth(dataset)}
        />
      )
    })
    return output
  }

  renderBezierShadow = config => {
    const {width, height, paddingRight, paddingTop, data} = config
    const output = []
    data.map((dataset, index) => {
      const d =
        this.getBezierLinePoints(dataset, config) +
        ` L${paddingRight +
          ((width - paddingRight) / dataset.data.length) *
            (dataset.data.length - 1)},${(height / 4) * 3 +
          paddingTop} L${paddingRight},${(height / 4) * 3 + paddingTop} Z`
      output.push(
        <Path
          key={index}
          d={d}
          fill="url(#fillShadowGradient)"
          strokeWidth={0}
        />
      )
    })
    return output
  }

  render() {
    const paddingTop = 16
    const paddingRight = 64
    const {
      width,
      height,
      data,
      withShadow = true,
      withDots = true,
      withInnerLines = true,
      withOuterLines = true,
      style = {},
      decorator,
      onDataPointClick
    } = this.props
    const {labels = []} = data
    const {borderRadius = 0} = style
    const config = {
      width,
      height
    }
    const datas = this.getDatas(data.datasets)
    return (
      <View style={style}>
        <Svg height={height} width={width}>
          <G>
            {this.renderDefs({
              ...config,
              ...this.props.chartConfig
            })}
            <Rect
              width="100%"
              height={height}
              rx={borderRadius}
              ry={borderRadius}
              fill="url(#backgroundGradient)"
            />
            <G>
                {withInnerLines
                    ? this.renderHorizontalLines({
                        ...config,
                        count: 4,
                        paddingTop,
                        paddingRight
                    })
                    : withOuterLines
                    ? this.renderHorizontalLine({
                        ...config,
                        paddingTop,
                        paddingRight
                    })
                    : null
                }
            </G>
            <G>
              {this.renderHorizontalLabels({
                ...config,
                count: Math.min(...datas) === Math.max(...datas) ? 1 : 4,
                data: datas,
                paddingTop,
                paddingRight
              })}
            </G>
            <G>
                {withInnerLines
                    ? this.renderVerticalLines({
                        ...config,
                        data: data.datasets[0].data,
                        paddingTop,
                        paddingRight
                    })
                    : withOuterLines
                    ? this.renderVerticalLine({
                        ...config,
                        paddingTop,
                        paddingRight
                    })
                    : null
                }
            </G>
            <G>
              {this.renderVerticalLabels({
                ...config,
                labels,
                paddingRight,
                paddingTop
              })}
            </G>
            <G>
              {this.renderLine({
                ...config,
                paddingRight,
                paddingTop,
                data: data.datasets
              })}
            </G>
            <G>
              {withShadow &&
                this.renderShadow({
                  ...config,
                  data: data.datasets,
                  paddingRight,
                  paddingTop
                })}
            </G>
            <G>
              {withDots &&
                this.renderDots({
                  ...config,
                  data: data.datasets,
                  paddingTop,
                  paddingRight,
                  onDataPointClick
                })}
            </G>
            <G>
              {decorator &&
                decorator({
                  ...config,
                  data: data.datasets,
                  paddingTop,
                  paddingRight
                })}
            </G>
          </G>
        </Svg>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LineChart
```

Answer (score 2):

I just change onDataPointClick function syntax error. and it's worked for me.

```
    <LineChart
     onDataPointClick={()=>{console.log('masoud')}} 
    // change here like this and it's work {()=>{console.log(masoud)}}
            data={{
              labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
              datasets: [{
                data: [
                  Math.random() * 100,
                  Math.random() * 100,
                  Math.random() * 100,
                  Math.random() * 100,
                  Math.random() * 100,
                  Math.random() * 100
                ]
              }]
            }} ...
```

full code is's here https://jsfiddle.net/s23b9u4p/

Comment: I want to get clicked value of each point of chart, I course, `onDataPointClick ` doesn't work to get value.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian can you share your project info. Did you link your project package?

Comment: I am definitely late but it might be helpful to someone @S.M_Emamian you can use
`onDataPointClick={({value, dataset, getColor}) => console.log('test:', value) }`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value of each click you need to have an array of your data and pass in value called index

```
<LineChart
            onDataPointClick={({index}) => {
              console.log(this.state.tickers[index]);
            }}
            data={{
              datasets: [
                {
                  data: this.state.tickers,
                },
              ],
            }}...
```